# "image contains error", trying to create and display images using google app engine

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-imaging-library

Hello all the general idea is to create a galaxy-like map. I run into problems when I try to display a generated image. I used Python Image library to create the image and store it in the datastore.

when i try to load the image i get no error on the log console and no image on the browser.
when i copy/paste the image link (including datastore key) i get a black screen and the following message:

> The image
>   “view-source:/localhost:8080/img?img_id=ag5kZXZ-c3BhY2VzaW0xMnINCxIHTWFpbk1hcBgeDA”
>   cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

the firefox error console:

> Error: Image corrupt or truncated:
>   /localhost:8080/img?img_id=ag5kZXZ-c3BhY2VzaW0xMnINCxIHTWFpbk1hcBgeDA

```
import cgi
import datetime
import urllib
import webapp2
import jinja2
import os
import math
import sys



from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users
from PIL import Image

#SNIP

#class to define the map entity
class MainMap(db.Model):
  defaultmap = db.BlobProperty(default=None)

#SNIP      


class Generator(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):

        #SNIP

        test = Image.new("RGBA",(100, 100))
        dMap=MainMap()
        dMap.defaultmap = db.Blob(str(test))
        dMap.put()

        #SNIP

        result = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM MainMap LIMIT 1").fetch(1)

        if result:
          print"item found<br>" #debug info

          if result[0].defaultmap:
              print"defaultmap found<br>" #debug info
              string = "<div><img src='/img?img_id=" + str(result[0].key()) + "' width='100' height='100'></img>"
              print string

        else:
            print"nothing found<br>"

    else:
        self.redirect('/?=error')
    self.redirect('/')


class Image_load(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("started Image load")
        defaultmap = db.get(self.request.get("img_id"))
        if defaultmap.defaultmap:
            try:
              self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
              self.response.out.write(defaultmap.defaultmap)
              self.response.out.write("Image found")
            except:
              print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
        else:
            self.response.out.write("No image")

#SNIP    



app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/generator', Generator),
                               ('/img', Image_load)],
                              debug=True)
```

the browser shows the "item found" and "defaultmap found" strings and a broken imagelink
the exception handling does not catch any errors

Thanks for your help
Regards
Bert

Answer (score 1):

The conversion of a PIL Image object to a string is not an image:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> i = Image.new("RGBA", (100, 100))
>>> str(i)
'<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=100x100 at 0x24C5DA0>'
```

Instead, you need to use the `save()` function and write it to a file. In app engine's case, you use a string buffer:

```
>>> import cStringIO
>>> s = cStringIO.StringIO()
>>> i.save(s, 'PNG')
>>> dMap.defaultmap = db.Blob(s.getvalue())
```

For ndb, when dMap.defaultmap is a `ndb.BlobProperty`:

```
>>> import cStringIO
>>> s = cStringIO.StringIO()
>>> i.save(s, 'PNG')
>>> dMap.defaultmap = s.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your image is a string

```
>>> test = Image.new("RGBA",(100, 100))
>>> test
<Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=100x100 at 0x1005EC878>
>>> str(test)
'<Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=100x100 at 0x1005EC878>'
```

The Image has a save method that can write it to a file-like object.

I'm thinking the following (untested) could work for blobstore if `defaultmap = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()`

```
from google.appengine.api import files
file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='image/png')
with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
    test.save(f, format='PNG')
files.finalize(file_name)
blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
```

or you could for example instantiate a StringIO and save to it, something like

```
from StringIO import StringIO
tmp = StringIO()
test.save(tmp, format='PNG')
dMap.defaultmap = db.Blob(tmp.getvalue())
```

Comment: thank you for your input. I have tried both your suggestions and th first one will not work because appengine does not allow any write (so test.save) actions. i get the following error : OSError: [Errno 13] path not accessible: 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs'. the second gives me the exact same symptoms when i use datastore.

Comment: I tried both examples locally in SDK and it works for me. Note that I did some edits, added files import and set format on save. File-like objects is key, it works on app engine because we don't write to file system, but to objects providing seek, tell and write methods. Do you have a problem with the PIL import perhaps?